# C# Control Two Motors according to the Mouseclicks on a Picturebox

Tags: c#

I am developing a C# win form GUI for controlling a two-motor XY stage. I have drawn a 100 x 100 square grid pattern on a picturebox in which each square, when clicked, represents a coordinate that the two motors must move to. I have studied this link
[PictureBox Grid and selecting individual cells when clicked on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711843/picturebox-grid-and-selecting-individual-cells-when-clicked-on) and this [PictureBox- Grids and Filling in squares (Game of Life)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737103/picturebox-grids-and-filling-in-squares-game-of-lifefor) for drawing a grid and marking the clicked positions.

Now I have to transform the series of randomly clicked points to actual movement of the two motors.

How shall I translate the click coordinates programmatically to give commands to control the motors?

I know how to move and control the motors without referring to the screen coordinates, i.e. by using eyes.

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Update1:
Hello... I think I am thinking too much in a confusing way to move the motors from one point to another despite Sebastien's great help. I wanted to try some logic below but I appreciate if somebody can enlighten me how best to implement this.

```
    private void pictureBoxGrid_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //int x = e.X;
        int x = cellSize * (e.X / cellSize);
        int y = cellSize * (e.Y / cellSize);
        int i = x / 8; // To limit the value to below 100
        int j = y / 8;

        // Reverse the value of fill_in[i, j] - if it was false, change to true,
        // and if true change to false
        fill_in[i, j] = !fill_in[i, j];

        if (fill_in[i, j])
        {
            //Save the coordinate in a list
            filledSq.Add(new Point(i, j));

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x + 1, y + 1, 7, 7);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //Delete the coordinate in a list
            filledSq.Remove(new Point(i, j));
            Color customColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight;

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
            using (SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(customColor))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(shadowBrush, x + 1, y + 1, 7, 7);
            }

        }
        //pictureBoxGrid.BackgroundImage = buffer;
        pictureBoxGrid.Invalidate();
    }

    private void buttonSavePoints_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // to be implemented...
    }

    private void buttonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var noOfDots = filledSq.Count;
        filledSq = filledSq.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y).ToList();
        var motor = new Motor();
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfDots; i++)
        {
          motor.Move(filledSq[i].X, filledSq[i].Y); //call the motor to move to X,Y here?
         //do sth at each position
        }
    }
```

Comment: this really depends on your motors, are these steppermotos or just normal ones? (steppermotors would make this way easier)

Comment: Hi, Sebastian L, Thanks for the reply. I am using the stepper motors. Actual control of the two motors are ok. What is stopping me is how to convert the points I click on the GUI into the real world movement of the motors. I now have a list of points, kind of like a storage bin of user-clicked coordinates. I sort of need a way to manipulate/transform that bin to move the motors. E.g. I click ten points randomly on the grid. Then the motors will move automaticallyto all ten points after I finish clicking. Hope it is clear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote, that you know how to move the motors programmatically this answer will be more theoretical:

Each steppermotor has a predefined anglewidth per step (e.g. 1.8°).
And if you know where your Motors are (for example at a predefined starting point with limitswitches (0|0)) you can calculate where they need to be.

For the precision there are multiple factors like if you are using Belts or threaded rods.

An examplemethod could look like this:

```
private static float stepwidth = 1.8;
private static beltConverionPerDegree = 0.2; // Or rod
private float currentPositionX = 0;
private float currentPositionY = 0;

public Tuple<int, int> GetSteps(float x, float y) {
    // calculate the position relative to the actual position (Vector between two points)
    float relativeX = x - currentPositionX;
    float relativeY = y - currentPositionY;

    return new Tuple<int, int> (relativeX / (stepwidth * beltConverionPerDegree), relativeY / (stepwidth * beltConverionPerDegree));
}
```

beltConverionPerDegree means how much distance your motor moves the belt for each degree.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, my stepper motor is of 1.8 Deg with Threaded Rod. I will have four limit switches, one for each end. So in my case, I have a list of coordinates "filledSq[ i, j]" from the mosueclicks of the square grid on the picturebox (i,j = 0,0 to 99,99 because the grid is 100 x 100), I just need to make use of the two coordinates for the motors to move and after moving, the first point of the last pair coordinates will be discarded then proceed to get another point, right? Sorry my C# is self-studied, i.e. limited.

Comment: i don't know if i understand you correctly, but as long as you keep track of your current position you can move to a new point and saving the new point as current position.

Comment: E.g. I click on square numbers (1,2), (20,30), (3,3), (5,3), (30,30). Now I need to 1. Sort the points (to move the motors efficiently), 2. Calibrate the motors to Home(0,0) position, 3. Go from Home to (1,2) then (3,3) 4. Discard (1,2) 5. Go to (5,3) from (3,3), 6. Discard (3,3), 7. Go to (20,30) from (5,3), 8. Discard (5,3), 9. Go to (30,30) from (20,30), 10. Discard (30,30), 11. End and Wait for another list. Is that the way to go about it?

Comment: Yes, Sebastien, I'm wondering how to keep track of the current position of the two motors.

Comment: when moving your motors to the new position just save the coordinates to a variable (in my example currentPositionX and Y)

Comment: Dear Sebastian, I've just found out that the "mouseclicks"(dots) on the grid disappear every time I minimize the window and maximize it again. Trying to troubleshoot. Please enlighten me if you got an idea. I am drawing the grid on _Paint event but the dots are being drawn by _MouseClick event. Thank you.